# importing polymer.html in sub-elements

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm getting my feet wet with Polymer.  I am wanting to create a stand-alone app that can be injected into multiple implementations.  Like this:

Inside my-app element, I may also have many sub-elements.  It's my understanding that every element needs to import polymer.html.  Should all of the sub-elements rely upon the parent (root) element to import polymer.html?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write all imports out for every element, so they are standalone. During [vulcanize](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize), unnecessary imports are ignored. So it does not matter how many polymer imports you have.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import polymer.html inside your elements. Just add it to the host page.

Inside your "main" element you can import all your sub elements or have all the imports inside one "elements.html" like the starter kit does.